# Не корректно отображается текстура OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, шейдеры, текстура

Учу OpenGL по урокам на хабре. Делаю текстуры. Используется библиотека stb_image. Проблема следующая: отображается среднее значение цвета текстуры. Никак не могу найти причину этого.
Вот код:

Mesh.cpp

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "Mesh.h"
Mesh::Mesh(vector<Vector3<GLfloat>> vertices, vector<unsigned int> indicles, vector<float> uvs) {
    cout<<"creating mesh stated\n";
    this->vertices = vertices;
    this->indices = indicles;
    this->UVs = uvs;
    //Shader newShader("StandartShader.vert", "StandartShader.frag");
    this->meshShader = Shader ("../src/GameSource/StandartSource/Shaders/StandartShader.vert", "../src/GameSource/StandartSource/Shaders/StandartShader.frag");//src\GameSource\StandartSource\Shaders
    InitMesh();
    cout<<"creating mesh finished\n";
}
Mesh::Mesh() {
    cout << "Warning! This mesh dosn't contain vertices data. Please, set them\n";
}
Mesh::~Mesh() {}
void Mesh::SetVertices(vector<Vector3<GLfloat>> verts) {
    Mesh::vertices = verts;
}
void Mesh::SetIndicles(vector<unsigned int> indicles) {
    Mesh::indices = indicles;
}
vector<Vector3<GLfloat>> Mesh::GetVertices() {
    return Mesh::vertices;
}
vector<unsigned int> Mesh::GetIndicles(){
    return Mesh::indices;
}
void Mesh::InitMesh() {
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    std::cout << "vertices size  =  " << vertices.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "indices size  =  " << indices.size() << "\n";
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vector3<GLfloat>), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // Position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertices.size() * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // Textures attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, UVs.size() * sizeof(float), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    // load and create a texture
    // -------------------------
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); // all upcoming GL_TEXTURE_2D operations now have effect on this texture object
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   // set texture wrapping to GL_REPEAT     (default wrapping method)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    // The FileSystem::getPath(...) is part of the GitHub repository so we can find files on any IDE/platform; replace it with your own image path.
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load("../src/GameSource/StandartSource/Textures/anypics.ru-56720.jpg",             &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
}
    std::cout << "\n\nquality is " << width << " * " << height << "\n\n";
    stbi_image_free(data);
    std::cout << " \n\n this is uvs length - " << UVs.size() << "\n";
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
void Mesh::Draw() {
    // bind Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    // create transformations
    glm::mat4 transform = glm::mat4(1.0f); // make sure to initialize matrix to identity matrix first
    transform = glm::translate(transform, glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f));
    transform = glm::rotate(transform, (float)glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    // get matrix's uniform location and set matrix
    meshShader.Use();
    unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(meshShader.Program, "transform");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);
}
void Mesh::Update() {
    Mesh::Draw();
}
```

StandartShader.vert

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    ourColor = aColor;
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

StandartShader.frag

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

// texture sampler
uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
}
```

Весь проект сразу:
[Ссылка на архив в Google диск](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GMeFlFOUXkcnaY8fUh63glc2O03LmGnH/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Получается вот это]

Comment: А координаты текстурные хорошие, нормированные?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить картинку к вопросу.

Comment: @gbg std::vector<float> с шестью значениями. 1.0f и 0.0f

Comment: Есть какая-то проблема с координатами вершин. Если я увеличиваю координату вершины по Y, она должна сместиться вверх, но так ведёт тебя только вершина 0. Вершины 1 и 3 смещаются влево. 2 вообще не смещается

Comment: Перед `glVertexAttribPointer` не видно bind-а соответствующего VBO, и передпоследний параметр выглядит странно.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, в вертексном шейдере у вас указана следующая позиция (2):
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;
Тогда как в атрибутах текстуры указано отображение позиции 1, которая отвечает за отображение цвета.

```
// Textures attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, UVs.size() * sizeof(float), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

Замените это и текстура должна будет отобразиться:

```
// Textures attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, UVs.size() * sizeof(float), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
```